# How to delete a corrupted Site Column

Tags: site-column

> Field type {field name} is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field.

According to most of the documentation out there, the only possible way to delete this column is with a database query. obviously that is out of the question. The next best solution is to contact Microsoft. Can SharePoint Stackexchange do any better?

Reference:

- [Remove Corrupted Site column](http://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/remove-sitecolumn-through-guid-2010remove-corrupted-site-columnfield-type-xxxxx-is-not-installed-properly-go-to-the-list-settings-page-to-delete-this-field-sharepoint2010/)
- [Removing a Corrupted Site Column in SharePoint 2010](http://jshidell.com/2012/06/07/removing-a-corrupted-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Corrupt site column cannot be deleted](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/05/corrupt-site-column-cannot-be-deleted.html)

My points :

- Cannot delete via the browser, as the page doesn't load with the above error
- Cannot delete with powershell, as iterating the `SPWeb.Fields` property gives the same error
- I'm currently looking into recreating a list with a reference to it

Comment: If you can, simply re-create the list..

Comment: I can't, I would have to hack it together by creating the list elsewhere, doing an export-spweb on the list, and manually editing the guids to point to the column, and for the column to point to the exported list

Comment: Actually that wouldnt work either, as this is a custom built "Type" - i.e. not a text field, date field, managed metadata field, lookup field, etc... i need to reactivte the feature that provided the type

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't touch the database. The SharePoint DB is very complex and you can break everything running queries on it.

If designer doesn't work for you, use PowerShell:

```
$webUrl = "http://theUrlOfYourCollection"
$columnName ="My column to delete"
$web = get-spweb $webUrl
$field = $web.Fields[$columnName]
$shadowField = $web.Fields[$field.TextField] # optional, only if the column has metadata
$field.Delete()
$shadowField.Delete() # optional, only if the column has metadata
$web.Update()
write-host "fields deleted" -foregroundcolor green
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: See point number 2 - In this case I could not iterate over the SPWeb.Fields enumeration

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot remove it by SharePoint UI, powershell, SPDesigner, SharePoint Manager remove it from the sql database. See here a [tutorial how to remove/delete corrupted SharePoint column](http://www.intrasolutions.nl/removing-a-corrupted-site-column-in-sharepoint/).

Answer (score 0):

I dont see this error yet but I Think that sharepoint manager can solve this and delete site column! (Or sharepoint Designer) test them before delete list!

[Sharepoint Manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8553.sharepoint-2010-manager.aspx)

Comment: This answer lacks a lot of details

Answer (score 0):

Open your site in SharePoint Designer. In the navigation panel select "Site Columns" and then find your site column in the list and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19411/how-to-remove-autogenerated-columns-created-by-designer-worflow/270546#270546)
I solved by problem following the steps using both SharePoint Manager and SharePoint Designer.